# To show P is a zero polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $P$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients that $n$ divides $P(2^n)$ for every positive integer $n$.

Prove that $P$ must be the zero polynomial.

What I did was apply some induction on the expression by considering $$P (x)= a_nx^n+ \cdots +a_0$$ which results in nothing for proving the required result.
Any hints/solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me how to use it...so that I can incorporate

Comment: Nikhil.....it would be highly beneficial if you can provide a rigorous proof...in the answer sectiom instead od the comments as it is not so helpful for me to catch

Comment: Nikhil why did you delete your post...it was beneficial

Comment: Whatever reuns said was correct but I feel too abrupt....a little more explanation can help.me understand better..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a prime $p$ divides $f(2^{mp})$ then it divides $f(2^m)$.

Comment: Reuns...can u explain a little bit

Comment: $2^p \equiv 2\bmod p$ thus $f((2^p)^m) \equiv f(2^m)\bmod p$

Comment: Fermat's little theorem

Comment: What's the next step after this?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout If $P\ne 0$ then for $m$ large enough $P(2^m)\ne 0$ so that every prime divides $P(2^{mp})$ thus $P(2^m)$ is a contradiction.