# Can you check this proof? Find all polynomials $P(x)$ with integer coefficients such that for each natural number $n, n$ divides $P(2^n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, solution-verification

Is this a good proof? I think it is allright but I am not sure. I want to prove this polynomial must be constant, with P(x)=0.

Suppose P isn't constant Let ord_p(2) denote the smallest number 0<k such that 2^k==1 mod p.
Let P be of degree k and leading coefficient A. Take p>A and P > 2^k. Then p|P(2^(tp)) for every t, meaning that 2^(tp) is a root of P mod p for every t. As 2^x==2^(x mod ord_p(2)), there is ord_p(2) unique roots of P mod p, all of which can be written as 2^(tp). But as 2^ord_p(2)>p>2^k then ord_p(2)>k, but this is a contradiction as P can have at most k roots mod p (because p does not divide A, as p>A).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%5Cmid%20P(2%5En)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apolynomial%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [Polynomial with integer coefficients](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2362319p19244615) and [n divides P(2^n)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1262192p6556902), with the latter thread stating the source is "$2016$ ELMO Problem $4$".

Comment: Your $a_i$s are complex numbers. Why should $(x-a_1)\dots(x-a_k)$ have integer coefficients? and if it doesn't, "$p|(2^p-a1)(2^p-a2)...(2^p-ak)$" doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: So, I think your proof is flawed. Here is a correct and simpler one: [To show P is a zero polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926033/to-show-p-is-a-zero-polynomial)

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah, it was careless to write it up like that, but the proof still works i think, due to the fact that P has at most deg P roots mod p?

Comment: Which proof? We cannot tell before you rewrite a careful one.